# How to get available processors in elixir?

Tags: elixir

In java available processors can be obtained by calling

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

What is the corresponding api in elixir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Elixir way of doing it is `System.schedulers/0` or `System.schedulers_online/0`, where the former is the total number of schedulers, and the latter is the total number of schedulers which are active (i.e., actually being used)

Answer (score 1):

The `:erlang` module provides this information with a `system_info` call:

```
:erlang.system_info(:schedulers_online)
```

Erlang abstracts CPUs away as "schedulers", and this API allows you to query how many are available.